# Row swap a float array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a matrix stored in a float array, and I need to swap a row of one matrix into another.

This is what I have done so far. The matrices m and m_new are a matrix class, where, 'float* m = new float(N*N)' is the class variable 'm'. I made a pointer to the row of the matrix where it needs to be swapped, and I used memcpy for the size of a row, 'N', to place that section of 'm' into 'm_new'. However, the values of m_new do not change, and I am confused why.

```
for (int variable : partition) {
    float* m_pt = m->m + (variable * N * sizeof(float));
    float* m_new_pt = m_new->m + (row * N * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(&m_new_pt, &m_pt, N*(sizeof(float)));
}
```

Comment: How do you determine that `m_new` does not change? Did you verify that the code actually runs?

Comment: Yes, I printed out the array and manually confirmed it. It is a matrix initialized to 0, and after this loop, it still remains with all 0.

Comment: Did you step through the code with a debugger and see the calculated addresses and the memcpy call?

Comment: You are passing a pointer to `m_pt` and `m_new_pt`. So you change (and overrun) the local variable not what it points to (i.e. the memory section holding your matrix row). Also, consider using `std::copy`.

Comment: `&m_new_pt` and `&m_pt` are not pointers to the data you want to copy, they are pointers to the variables `m_new_pt` and `m_pt`. Drop the `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue, you should remove the `&` operator in the `memcpy` function. `m_new_pt` and `m_pt` are already pointers, so they already contain addresses. By using the `&` operator, you are passing the addresses of the pointers, not the addresses of the data. Memcpy to copy the addresses themselves, not the data behind them.

```
for (int variable : partition) {
    float* m_pt = m->m + (variable * N);
    float* m_new_pt = m_new->m + (row * N);
    memcpy(m_new_pt, m_pt, N * sizeof(float));
}
```